# Not able to access the server hosted in the local network from another box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, networking

Hosted a ruby on rails application in a box on port number 3000 and was able to access it from the local browser. I am trying to access the website from another box belonging to the same network. It is saying that "This site can’t be reached". I added that public ip of the box to the hosts file. Please let me know how to access the server hosted in the box from the local network.

Comment: post your public ip

Comment: "_I added that public ip of the box to the hosts file._" That's incorrect. Use the _local_ address in the hosts file. You are trying to do hairpin routing, and that is not the way to do it.